# What issues arise when using Openstack Swift SAIO for Production use?

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

### Swift Use Case

I am currently working on an application that could leverage the ability to add in custom middleware into Swift. Currently that involves a custom auth middleware module, but could be added onto in the future. The project needs object storage that Swift can provide, but the scale is relatively small and does not require the full Openstack ecosystem.

Therefore, Swift All in One (SAIO) seems like a useful tool for just having a Swift deployment for use.

### Question

All documentation I come across for SAIO states is for [development purposes](https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/development_saio.html). However I haven't seen any explanation for why it can't be used for production. So could SAIO be used for production if the storage is configured properly and no other Openstack components are needed?

Comment: I don’t know about SAIO but could Ceph be an alternative for you? It offers three different protocols, one of them being object storage (S3). It definitely is production grade software although it has a high learning curve at the beginning. But setting it up is very quick. Here’s a link to the docs: https://ceph.io/en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with OpenStack-swift more than 3 years in production. And I strongly confirmed that There are many reasons SAIO is not belong production environment.
In your situiation, I think you can split SAIO into 2 components :

- swift-proxy nodes: swift-proxy processes and all middlewares - You can easily custom your middleware in this component.
- swift-storage nodes: account-server, container-server, object-server processes, storage devices  - scale out disk space.